# how to recursively find a solution for N queen problem

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that can take a partial solution to a problem and give a solution. 
I am given a board of size MxN , where I should attempt to place K queens given a partial solution of K'

for example the following board:

```
 Q X * * 
 * * Q * 
 * * X *
 * * X *
```

the function should take this board, and the indexes 1 for row and 2 for column, the current number of queens on it - 2 and the final number of queens to be on it - 4.
I'm only allowed to add queens on the rowth row from the colth column to the end of that row,
and any following row for any column
in this example -  (1,3), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)
the function should print true because it is possible .. for example the following:

```
 Q X * * 
 * * Q * 
 * * X *
 * Q X Q
```

however my function doesn't quite do that and I can't see why..

```
   private static boolean kQueens(int[][] board, int k, int row, int col, int numOfQueens) {

    if (numOfQueens == k) return true;

    //trying to place a queen in the row at the col+1 ~ row length position.
    // if possible place it and try to place a new one in the next position.
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            //save the value of that position in case we'll need to change it back
            int tmp = board[i][j];
            if (addQueen(board, i, j)) {
                board[i][j] = QUEEN;
            }
            if (kQueens(board, k, i, j, numOfQueens + 1)) {

                return true;
            }
           //remove the queen and backtrack
            board[i][j]=tmp;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is a university assignment. I do not think anyone will solve it for you

Comment: Why is your example a valid solution? You have a queen at (0,0) and one at (3,3).

Comment: because there's a wall separating them so that they don't threaten each other

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution, I'm asking for assistance because I can't see what's going wrong and I'm stuck..